# Check the time , day and setText of an empty TextView (Like a Schedule, if time is between 16:00 and 17:00 on a sunday setText to "Naptime")

Tags: javascript, android, date, time, schedule

ANDROID
My resources-:
Button button
Textview textview_empty

I want to make a function to check the time and-:
setText textview_empty to a particular text.
Please help
If it was javascript the code would be:

```
<p id=a></p>
<script>

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
if (currentTime >= 16 && currentTime <= 17) {
   document.body.style.background = "#58FA58";
} else {
    document.body.style.background = "#013ADF";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
TextView mTextView;
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_empty);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String hour = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
String minute = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String seconds = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

String formattedTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;

mTextView.setText(formattedTime);
```